# Reason to create fake accounts using real email addresses

Tags: web-application, account-security

I've been dealing with a problem that I can't solve until I find the cause.
We get regularly accounts made with scraped/leaked emails and random names. They are useless because you need to verify the email before logging in, so they remain inactive. Usually, a failed register attempt wouldn't bother me, but people receive activation emails of accounts they didn't create, some mark those emails as spam, and that really bothers me.

If I'd knew why would anyone create such accounts, I'd be able to mitigate them in some way. I already have some checks in place, captcha pops up after the first inactive account from the same IP, but bots got kind of smart.

Does anyone have a clue of what would be the use for such accounts?

Comment: Why do you need to understand the cause before you develop a solution? As with any other account policy procedure, deactivate the account after a period of inactivity. In this case, if the account is not activated by the user after a month, then purge.

Comment: The problem is that i can't prevent account creation without shooting myself in the foot. Detecting and purging such accounts isn't a problem. The accounts are not active, and they will never be activated unless a victim actually clicks the activation link (unlikely).

Comment: So, what is your goal here? To prevent people from trying to sign up in the first place? You want to qualify the person before sending that first email?

Comment: I would like to remove the incentive for creating these accounts.

Comment: ... that's not something under your control ...

Comment: Without knowing what your site does and what access having an account offers, I'm afraid we're guessing why people would want to get an account on your service.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. The solution is to put into place an email verifier. Usually the email sending services have an option to enable this and use all kinds of techniques to detect if they are fake or not (for example [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/email-api/email-address-validation-api/)).

As to why this happens - spam. They want to spam with affiliate links and other spam that makes it worth developing these automated tools. Automated tools don't always know to detect that there is "more" to the sign up process such as a verification email or SMS. You can read more about it [here](https://mailchimp.com/help/about-fake-signups/).

Comment: But the OP concedes that the emails are legit, so a verifier does not seem to be relevant.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that the OP is running a service that allows for accounts to make comments to the public. Let's get some details before going down a specific path.

Comment: Over time we had these spam problems (like everybody), but gradually suppressed the abusers by removing user controlled content from emails, public facing pages and so on. Again, you can't log in without a verified account, so even if you could spam from an account, this is not the case, since the register attempts are not completed with email validation.

Comment: @schroeder: My interpretation of the answer is not that the website in question allows making comments to the public, but that it's found by bots searching for websites which allow making comments to the public.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that prospects have absolutely no privileges.  If possible store them outside of the regular user list.

Put a CAPTCHA before sending the verification email.  This will deter automated attacks

Check that your verification form is immune to SMTP injection attacks. Check you outbound email logs to ensure that only the intended emails are being created. log formdata from the sign-ups and look for suspicious content.

Answer (score 0):

A victim kindly gave us the info. It appears he was hit with a case of mail bombing (email  flooding) in which he received thousands of emails, probably to hide attacks (password resets and so on).
Not much you can do about that if you're on such a list, we mitigated by showing captcha by default to all IPs from Russia. Works for now, but it's not a strong and lasting solution. Any other options are welcomed.

Comment: So, you can see the foundational problem with your question that I was getting to. Understanding (or trying to guess at) the cause or trying to influence the cause is not the way to go. The only power you have is to treat the symptoms.